# Sort-Merge-Join Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, database, algorithm

My code:

```
 def merge_join(self, outer, outer_join_index, inner, inner_join_index):
    a=list(inner)
    b=list(outer)
    if not a or not b:
        return
    inner_copy = sorted(a,key=lambda tup: tup[inner_join_index])
    outer_copy = sorted(b,key=lambda tup: tup[outer_join_index])
    inner_counter=0
    outer_counter=0
    while inner_counter < len(inner_copy) and outer_counter < len(outer_copy):
        if outer_copy[outer_counter][outer_join_index]==inner_copy[inner_counter][inner_join_index]:
            yield outer_copy[outer_counter]+inner_copy[inner_counter]
            outer_counter+=1
        elif outer_copy[outer_counter][outer_join_index]<inner_copy[inner_counter][inner_join_index]:
            outer_counter+=1
        else:
            inner_counter+=1
```

Where outer and inner are generators.

I ran a given test for the algorithm but it returned a generator of 127 elements as opposed to the expected number 214. Can anyone help me check where the bug might be in my code? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pick a correct `outer` row for each `inner` row (without duplicates in `inner` and skipping rows if there's no match then in case of match you are supposed to increment `inner_counter`, not `outer_counter` like you are doing.

The reason is that otherwise if multiple inner rows have the same value you will only output the first of them.

If instead you want to do a full join (producing all the cartesian product of rows from `inner` and `outer` for a given value of the join column) then this has to be coded explicitly with something like

```
while inner_counter < len(inner_copy) and outer_counter < len(outer_copy):
    key = min(inner_copy[inner_index][inner_join_index],
              outer_copy[outer_index][outer_join_index])
    inner_group = []
    while inner_index < len(inner) and key == inner_copy[inner_index][inner_join_index]:
        inner_group.append(inner_copy[inner_index])
        inner_index += 1
    outer_group = []
    while outer_index < len(outer) and key == outer_copy[outer_index][outer_join_index]:
        outer_group.append(outer_copy[outer_index])
        outer_index += 1
    # Here you can handle left or right join by replacing an
    # empty group with a group of one empty row (None,)*len(row)
    for i in inner_group:
        for o in outer_group:
            yield i + o
```